# What happened to Goku after he destroyed Freeza on Namek? (Instant Transmission)

Tags: dragon-ball, dragon-ball-z

I remember Goku destroying Freeza on Namek and then he disappears after that. (He won't return to earth).
I thought there was some mystery behind the whole Instant Transmission thing.

**When Vegeta went to hunt down Goku he did find someone.** I found a video on youtube [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4gQDBmJHsNQ)

Now when Goku returned to earth, just after Future Trunks killed Freeza, Goku told the story about how he learnt Instant Transmission Technique and all.

But, Guku denies facing Vegeta. Who was that Guy in the video then? Or Guku just simply lie about **Instant Transmission**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When Namek is blowing up **Goku** gets into one of the Ginyu force ships and sets off to explore the galaxy.

Whilst out there he meets a race called **the Yardrat** who after some time teach him how to perform the Instant Transmission technique.

In the manga (the comics written before the anime which they were based on) Vegeta never goes on his search he simply trains on earth for the time in which Goku is missing and that's how Vegeta becomes a super saiyan.

The point of the clip you posted is to merely show the moment in which Vegeta realised how to become a super saiyan, to give more of a meaning or more of a reason as to why he couldn't do it before.

It's never actually explained but there are two likely scenarios

1. In a state of temporary psychosis at his inability to find Goku and turn into a super saiyan, Vegeta has a Hallucinated epiphany which allows him to see the light (hehe) and turn into a super saiyan.
2. It was Goku but he was training with meteors and upon sensing Vegetas Ki he fled back to the Yardrat or elsewhere in the galaxy to continue his training unhindered.

Personally option 1 is more likely, Goku is a lot of things but a liar he is not. He would most likely not have fled Vegeta but have welcomed a fight. He also would have mentioned it when he arrived back on earth.

**TL:DR** Vegeta went crazy with self induced inadequacies and had an epiphany.

*Also the anime creators wanted to make it seem like a bigger deal*

Comment: Yap. Goku won't lie. That's why he is a role model for every kid of our age. I'll go with 1. And thanks for letting me know about the change in Comic and Animation Series. These guys really need to stop making off comic topics.

Comment: @Drag0nKn1ght It happens a lot as just filler stuff to make the shows more suspenseful and exciting. (One of my other DBZ answers mentions another inaccuracy if you're interested)